# Reverse the direction of all sequences of letters in a string

Tags: php, substring, reverse

Is it possible to reverse only the letters in a string?

For instance  if I have the word `$word = "word,!";`

I need the result to be `$result = "drow,!";`

I tried using `strrev`, but it reverses the punctuation marks too.

Comment: Split the string, use `strrev` on the word, then concatenate the results with the punctuation.

Comment: Is there a possibility to have punctuation marks in the middle? Or the will be only at the beginning / end?

Comment: is there a limited set of punctuation marks? or do you only want to reverse letters in a string that can contain anything?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 $word = "word,!pineapple--pizza";
 $revd = preg_replace_callback('#([A-Za-z]+)#', 'rev_first', $word);

function rev_first($matches){
    return strrev($matches[1]);
}
```

http://3v4l.org/PXEs8

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I was preparing an anwser, but this looks best. I'd just use `\w` instead of `[A-Za-z]`.

Comment: @Savageman I was going to use that, but word characters includes underscores and numbers, which isn't what he's asking for, since I'd not consider either of those letters.

Answer (score 0):

try with `preg_replace_callback`

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('/\w+/', function($found) {
    foreach ($found as $value) {
        return strrev($value);
    }
}, "Hello, word,!");

echo $result; // olleH, drow,!
```

Comment: Why `foreach()` if you unconditionally `return` on the first iteration of the matches array?

Answer (score 0):

I need to refine and modernize the accepted answer.

There is no need to use a capture group when the fullstring match is identical to the captured substring.  A case-insensitive pattern flag will reduce the length of the character class. From PHP7.4, arrow function syntax makes anonymous function syntax more concise.

An important note is that neither the pattern nor `strrev()` is yet prepared to handle multibyte letters.  If anyone needs this extended scope, search for similar Stack Overflow pages that handle multibyte strings.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GXARX))

```
$string = "word,!pineapple--pizza";
echo preg_replace_callback(
         '~[a-z]+~i',
         fn($m) => strrev($m[0]),
         $string
     );
```